# JqGrid Primary Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Can any Body tell me how to configure primary key in JqGrid.
Since Jqgrid uses id as primary key But I am using something else than id so can you tell me how to configure that.

Comment: Could you explain more clear what you mean. An example would be good. Currently you use wrong terminology. The jqGrid has no "primary keys", but there as rowids, `key:true` option in the `colModel` and some information about ids from JSON or XML data. What you mean? Do you use remote data in the jqGrid (`datatype:'json'` or `datatype:'xml'`) and try to fill jqGrid with the data from the database?

Answer (score 0):

I use the jsonReader attribute to set the PrimaryKey by name.

```
jQuery("#ajaxGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GridData")',
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "PrimaryKey" },
```